# How to speed up a script?

Tags: javascript, performance, drupal, drupal-6

I'm using drupal and I got this script for finding comments. If you know drupal then you know about the notorious issue which is that if you click on a link to a comment and that comment is not on page 1 then you won't get anywhere. The script is addressing this issue by finding comment and taking you to the right page but lord is it slow.. My question: Is there any way to speed it up at all?

```js
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, r) {
    e = function(c) {
        return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
        k = [
            function(e) {
                return r[e]
            }
        ];
        e = function() {
            return '\\w+'
        };
        c = 1
    };
    while (c--)
        if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
    return p
}('(6(){r(D,"E",6(){s();2 a=9.F("a");k(2 i=0;i<a.l;i++){2 b=a[i];3(/#g-\\d/.m(b.7))b.7=b.7.t("#",(/\\?/.m(b.7)?"&":"?")+"G=1#")}});6 r(a,b,c){u{a.H(b,c,I)}v(w){u{a.J("K"+b,c)}v(w){}}}6 s(){3(!/#g-\\d+$/.m(5.o))4;2 a;3(a=9.x(5.o.h(1)))4;2 b=5.L.h(1).y("&");j("z",b);2 c=+j("A",b);3(c&&9.x("g-"+c))4;2 d=+j("B",b);3(d>=M)4;2 e=p(9.N);3(e){2 f=5.7.O(/.*?(?=\\?|#|$)/)+"?B="+(d+1)+"&A="+e+(b+""?"&"+b.P("&"):"")+5.o;3(c)5.t(f);Q 5=f}}6 p(a){k(2 b R a.C){2 c=a.C[b];3(c.q&&c.q.h(0,8)==="g-")4+c.q.h(8);2 n=p(c);3(n)4 n}}6 j(a,b){k(2 i=0;i<b.l;i++){2 c=b[i].y("=");3(c[0]===a){b.S(i,1);4(c.l>=1)?c[1]:""}}4""}}());', 55, 55, '||var|if|return|location|function|href||document|||||||comment|substr||removeSearchValue|for|length|test||hash|getFirstCommentNumber|id|addEvent|commentLink|replace|try|catch|ignore|getElementById|split||cs|page|childNodes|window|load|getElementsByTagName|cl|addEventListener|false|attachEvent|on|search|99|body|match|join|else|in|splice'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

Comment: Where did you get the script? It would probably be useful to provide the original unpacked version if you want help optimising; http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html

Answer (score 0):

So here is the unpacked version of your code.

The function `getFirstCommentNumber` is recursive calling itself on all child nodes of the parameter it recieves and the function `commentLink` calls this using `document.body`. Basically you are traversing the entire DOM structure looking for a comment number.

Is there a better DOM node that just contains the comments you can pass inside `commentLink` into the `getFirstCommentNumber` call?

```js
(function () {
 addEvent(window, "load", function () {
  commentLink();
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0;
   i < a.length;
   i++) {
   var b = a[i];
   if (/#comment-\d/.test(b.href))
    b.href = b.href.replace("#", (/\?/.test(b.href) ? "&" : "?") + "cl=1#")
  }
 });
 function addEvent(a, b, c) {
  try {
   a.addEventListener(b, c, false)
  } catch (ignore) {
   try {
    a.attachEvent("on" + b, c)
   } catch (ignore) {}
  }
 }
 function commentLink() {
  if (!/#comment-\d+$/.test(location.hash))
   return;
  var a;
  if (a = document.getElementById(location.hash.substr(1)))
   return;
  var b = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
  removeSearchValue("z", b);
  var c = +removeSearchValue("cs", b);
  if (c && document.getElementById("comment-" + c))
   return;
  var d = +removeSearchValue("page", b);
  if (d >= 99)
   return;
  var e = getFirstCommentNumber(document.body);
  if (e) {
   var f = location.href.match(/.*?(?=\?|#|$)/) + "?page=" + (d + 1) + "&cs=" + e + (b + "" ? "&" + b.join("&") : "") + location.hash;
   if (c)
    location.replace(f);
   else
    location = f
  }
 }
 function getFirstCommentNumber(a) {
  for (var b in a.childNodes) {
   var c = a.childNodes[b];
   if (c.id && c.id.substr(0, 8) === "comment-")
    return +c.id.substr(8);
   var n = getFirstCommentNumber(c);
   if (n)
    return n
  }
 }
 function removeSearchValue(a, b) {
  for (var i = 0;
   i < b.length;
   i++) {
   var c = b[i].split("=");
   if (c[0] === a) {
    b.splice(i, 1);
    return (c.length >= 1) ? c[1] : ""
   }
  }
  return ""
 }
}
 ());
```

Comment: @user4843525 then you won't have any real chance of optimising the code